# module cx_Oracle has no attribute 'init_oracle_client'

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I was trying to run following command but getting "module cx_Oracle has no attribute 'init_oracle_client'" error in python version 3.7. but same command working find in version 3.6. Can anyone help me in fixing this.

```py
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"path of oracle instant client")
```

Comment: what error are you getting ? are you using mac-os ?

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade cx_Oracle in your Python 3.7 installation:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade cx_Oracle
```

The `init_oracle_client()` function was introduced in 8.0, see the [release notes](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release_notes.html#version-8-0-june-2020).

Alternatively use the traditional configuration on Windows of adding your Oracle client library directory to PATH before you run Python.